# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 on Samsung EVO 970 NVMe

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, format

I have Windows 10 already installed on hard drive.
I want to install Ubuntu 22.04 on the EVO 970 which was previously reformatted.
I am considering disconnecting all the SATA drives including the one with the Windows OS so that when booting from the Ubuntu USB, only the EVO 970 ssd is "seen"
The BIOS is UEFI that identifies the EVO 970 ssd

How and what type of formatting should I use from the Ubuntu install menu for the EVO 970?

Comment: You use whatever format you wish for your *unstated* Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product (be it Server, Desktop or *flavor*). Different installers are used for different products, but if you want to specify everything yourself you can also via *Something else*, *Manual Partitioning* or whichever product/ISO you elect to use

Comment: Go with the default options. Ubuntu will erase everything in your SSD and format it `ext4`. This is in my opinion the best option for you.

Comment: Disconnecting all drives except the EVO is a good idea, especially if you are new to Linux. Unexpected things can happen but what you suggest avoids that. After you reconnect the Windows HDD you will probably want to update grub so that Windows appears as an option on the grub menu

Comment: If Windows 10 is UEFI, which most are. You need to be sure to boot live installer in UEFI boot mode. How you boot install media, is then how it installs. You also want gpt partitioning particularly with UEFI installs. If drive is blank, UEFI install will default to gpt. But if partitioning in advance, gparted, still seems to default to very old MBR. With gparted, before starting adding partitions, select gpt under device tab, advanced over msdos(MBR) default partitioning before starting. That will totally erase drive, so make sure any data is backed up.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. Installation was successful.